# textview does not update it's position on adjustResize

Tags: java, android, xml

Basically, I used

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

in my Manifest.xml file so that the edittext appears when the softkeyboard arrives but now the text view above the edittext is not moving, I know that it is because that the text view is visible, how do I solve this is what I can not figure out. Is it possible that the text view changes position with respect to the edit text? I also write this in the text view tried

```
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/getEmail"
```

where getEmail is the id of the edit text, but the text view only disappears now

Following is my xml file code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".GetEmailActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewGetEmail"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/getEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="215dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/getEmail"
        android:fontFamily="times"
        android:text="Enter Email Here:"
        android:textColor="#5a0c0c"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/getEmail" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/getEmail"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:fontFamily="times"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:hint="email@provider.com"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/errorEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/getEmail"
        android:layout_marginBottom="220dp"
        android:fontFamily="times"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/getEmail" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="270dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:text="next"
        android:onClick="check"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[Image of how it looks before the keyboard arrives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndlVX.png)

[Image of how it looks like after keyboard arries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKNBc.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to Remove this line  `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/getEmail"` from First Textview should be like this and set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustpan"` in manifest

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewGetEmail"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/getEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="215dp"
        android:fontFamily="times"
        android:text="Enter Email Here:"
        android:textColor="#5a0c0c"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/getEmail" />
```